# Magento 1.9 - how to set rules to invalidate old “version numbers” for the cache’s store on the client’s local computers

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, htaccess

I have been suffered from users on my website couldn't see the update because of cache. On searching on Google, most of posts are noted like just flushing cache on back-end site and via FTP.

Btw even me from development team, when i didn't clear cache on my own browser, i couldn't see the image i just updated.

So i want to know about cache management which can control how quickly client's will see updated version of our site.
And option our development team can pursue is cache management via .htaccess. I would need to set rules to invalidate old “version numbers” for the cache’s store on the client’s local computers.

Could you share your opinion about this? Thank you so much!